# How to run Robot web tools at Non Internet environment?

Tags: ros-kinetic, rosbridge, rosbridge-suite, robotwebtools, nav2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am trying to create some widgets for RobotWebTools to monitor/control my robot on the Web browser remotely. According to the nav2djs(one of the widgets of the RobotWebTools) [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/nav2djs/Tutorials/CreatingABasicNav2DWidget), the HTML code was shown. So, I decided to use this code as a Base and modify for my original. The code includes the line as below.
My robot and other equipment such as laptop and tablet are all connected in the same Network. However, it is not connected to the Internet. It means all ".js" files cannot import from http://cdn~~~.
I sought for each JS file in order to download and place at the same directory as the HTML file. However, I couldn't find most of those.
Does anyone have some solution of this?

Thank you in advance.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EaselJS/current/easeljs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EventEmitter2/current/eventemitter2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/roslibjs/current/roslib.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/ros2djs/current/ros2d.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/nav2djs/current/nav2d.min.js"></script>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318883/how-to-run-robot-web-tools-at-non-internet-environment?/) by [yoshiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/36541/yoshiros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yoshiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/36541/yoshiros/) on 2019-03-19**:
Oh! I have just forgotten the wonderful command in Ubuntu "wget" till your comment. Thanks!

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2019-03-19**:
Mind closing the issue then if you fixed the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Simple solution. Download JS's by 'wget' command and change the pass in the code.
CDN server is stopping now for some reason. The solution is to change "cdn" to "static".
Download example(download to the same directory as HTML file)

```
$ wget -p /home/common/htmls "http://static.robotwebtools.org/EaselJS/current/easeljs.min.js"
```

and change the line from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.robotwebtools.org/EaselJS/current/easeljs.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="easeljs.min.js"></script>
```

worked.

Reference. How to download in Ubuntu terminal: ["How to download a file from a website via terminal?"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207265/how-to-download-a-file-from-a-website-via-terminal)

---

Originally posted by [yoshiros](https://answers.ros.org/users/36541/yoshiros/) with karma: 69 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try downloading those files into your repo and changing the source address?

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2